# AngularJS Create new scope in template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, symfony, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Using Symfony2.x, I have a twig loop going through data for some data, and I also have an `ng-repeat` going on for similar elements (difference being these ones get loaded in the background though), but both are to share the same functionality.

I have some odd functionality going on in the twig loop versions that are working perfectly fine in the `ng-repeat` versions. I have a feeling it's simply a scope issue.

I read in the docs that `ng-repeat` will automatically create a new scope for the repeated elements, but of course this doesn't happen with a twig loop.

How does one manually, and preferably exclusively IN the template, invoke a new scope per repeated element?

Comment: manually you have to use   scope = $currentscope.$new();

Comment: where would I place that? Sorry still newish to Angular, probably should have specified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way might be to add a directive to each element.  This can be done in the template. The directive can then request new scope (via `scope:true` or `scope:{}`) and each repeated element will get a new scope associated with it.

You can create a directive on an element like:

```
<div mydirective></div>
```

Then in your code, define the directive:

```
myApp.directive('mydirective',function(){
    return {
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            // do some scope / element stuff here
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry still newish to Angular, what would be the process in doing this?  

<any ng-scope:true > ?

Comment: Please see my updated answer.  If you still need more info, maybe you can post your loop / template code.

Comment: OH sorry i thought you were referring to an existing directive of angular's, thank you for the code example though, that will help

Comment: No problem :) feel free to post the template if you'd like