# Can I declare a variable in html?

Tags: angularjs

Given

```
 <li>Document Printing - 
<a href="http://{{displaySandbox()}}/{{displayCase()}}/PrintingService/DocumentPrintingService.svc">
 <span ng-class="{true:'value',false:'invalid'}[(sandbox && validcase())==true]">http://<span class="sandbox">{{displaySandbox()}}</span>.companyname.com/<span class="case">{{displayCase()}}</span>/PrintingService/DocumentPrintingService.svc</span></a> 
<span ng-bind-html-unsafe="getUrl('/PrintingService/DocumentPrintingService.svc')">
</span>
</li>
```

I would like to declare something like to wrap this in

```
<div ng-var="subPath=/PrintingService/PrintingService.svc>
```

so that anything inside that scope would be able to say

```
    <li>Document Printing - 
<a href="http://{{displaySandbox()}}/{{displayCase()}}{{subPath}}">
 <span ng-class="{true:'value',false:'invalid'}[(sandbox && validcase())==true]">http://<span class="sandbox">{{displaySandbox()}}</span>.companyname.com/<span class="case">{{displayCase()}}</span>{{subPath}}</span></a> 
<span ng-bind-html-unsafe="getUrl(subPath)">
</span>
</li>
```

Is there a way to declare a scope (for a variable or 'constant' if you will), via `angular.js` in html?

Comment: Yes, there's [`ng-init`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInit).

Comment: so inside each template the `ng-bind-html-unsafe` won't have a problem with a modified closure?

Comment: this fails for the reasons I expected it would: http://jsfiddle.net/5Ag8C/

Comment: `ng-bind-html-unsafe` doesn't create a scope, so the scope is not closed. That could be a problem

Comment: I notice that you use href directly, instead you should use ng-href. You could use ng-bind to set value of the subPath and use in ng-href

Comment: @basav - does that take care of the scoping/closure issues?

Comment: @Maslow You can create a scope for each set of divs by using a dumb directive. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720523/angularjs-create-new-scope-in-template

Answer (score 5):

Using `ng-init`, you can initialize a value as below:

```
 <data ng-init="subPath= '/PrintingService/PrintingService.svc'"/>
```

However, it is better to use controller in such cases.

[ng-init doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)